# How to create a browser based YouTube upload for a specific channel without user login

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a college channel on youtube for registered students(of the college website) to upload videos. 
Using YouTubeAPIv3 direct upload using java and the client key was possible for a stored video.
Students have to upload to college channel within the website.
How to upload from browser without them logging in?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to upload video without logging in. You must have an account and use its credentials all the time.

These document might help you how to upload video on youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php?csw=1#Direct_Upload